# Why this gradient is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve gradient text as told by one of the member in stack flow 
Below is my MainActivity class where I calling my Draw2d class which draws the canvas

```
public class TextEffectsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     TextView secondTextView = new TextView(this);    
     secondTextView.setText(R.id.textView6);

     Draw2d d = new Draw2d(this, secondTextView);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);   
     setContentView(d);   
}
```

here is my draw2d class Where check the end of the code for gradient I am using shader

```
public class Draw2d extends View{

  TextView secondTextView;
  public Draw2d(Context context, TextView tv) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    secondTextView=tv;        
    }    
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {        
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.drawColor(R.color.VeryLightGrey);        
       Paint p = new Paint();

     // For gradient in text  
       Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 0,new int[]{Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN},
            null, TileMode.CLAMP);  // null or new float[]{0.5f,1.0f}
       secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should do that before drawing color,

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 0,
            new int[]{Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN},
            null, TileMode.CLAMP);            // null or new        float[]{0.5f,1.0f}
    secondTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
    canvas.drawColor(R.color.VeryLightGrey);


     // For gradient in text  






}
```